# Two sites on one Apache Installation

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2, websites, bugzilla

I have Observium installed on my Admin Cloud instance, I also need to add Bugzilla on to this server.

I have installed Bugzilla successfully - /var/www/html/bugzilla
Observium - /opt/observium

I have setup the conf like this:

/etc/apache2/sites-available/bugzilla

```
 <VirtualHost *:8080>
     ServerName bugzilla
     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bugzilla
<Directory />
       AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
       Options +ExecCGI
       DirectoryIndex index.cgi index.html
       AllowOverride All
</Directory>
ErrorLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
ServerSignature On
```

and

/etc/apache2/sites-available/observium.conf

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName observium
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /opt/observium/html
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /opt/observium/html/>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
ServerSignature On
```

And added Listen 80 & Listen 8080 in ports.conf

But the only site available is obsevium.

Have a missed something??????

Thanks :)

Comment: Isn't `http://bugzilla:8080` working?

Comment: No, it searches then, The connection has timed out

It's a cloud server so can't access like that.

Comment: Is the port 8080 open into the firewall?

Comment: Maybe you may rename .conf file from `/etc/apache2/sites-available/bugzilla` to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/bugzilla.conf` and execute `a2ensite bugzilla`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the new configuration, then reload apache. I would recommend renaming your bugzilla to bugzilla.conf. You can copy the default one and rename it.

```
sudo a2ensite bugzilla
```

or

```
sudo a2ensite bugzilla.conf
```

Reloading Apache

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add multiple sites via adding host entries in host file

```
/etc/hosts
```

Comment: Thanks but i did that - 127.0.0.1 localhost observium bugzilla

Comment: Are they all on one line ?